# I need to make multiple copies of a file with a specific filename

Tags: batch-file, copy

I need to create several thousand files which are a duplicate of one (image) file in a flight simulator project.

The destination files already exist in the simulation, but all 4,241 of them are the same 86kb dds file. I have manipulated one of these images and now need to replace the existing files.

I've got a text file with the names of the files that need to be created, but lack the skill with automating the task of copying the one file that many times with the required file name.

Can anybody assist me with what I'm assuming would be a relatively simple operation to make a copy of the master file iterating each copy with a 'filename' from within the text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (yourtextfile.txt) do echo(copy "yoursourcefile.ext" "%%a"
```

Note : will simply report the command for verification purposes. When you're happy, change the `echo(copy` to `copy` to activate the copy.

Append `>nul` to the line to suppress `1 file(s) copied` message.

change `copy` to `copy /y` to overwrite existing file(s)

This is a line in a batch file. If running directly from the prompt, reduce each `%%a` to `%a`